# Vectorization - Adding numpy arrays without loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

So I have the following numpy arrays:

```
c = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12]])
X = array([[10, 15, 20,  5],
           [ 1,  2,  6, 23]])
y = array([1, 1])
```

I am trying to add each `1x4` row in the `X` array to one of the columns in `c`. The `y` array specifies which column. The above example, means that we are adding both rows in the `X` array to column `1` of c. That is, we should expect the result of:

```
     c = array([[ 1,  2+10+1,  3],  =  array([[ 1,  13,  3],
                [ 4,  5+15+2,  6],            [ 4,  22,  6],
                [ 7,  8+20+6,  9],            [ 7,  34,  9],
                [10, 11+5+23, 12]])           [10,  39, 12]])
```

Does anyone know how I can do this without any loops? I tried `c[:,y] += X` but it seems like this only adds the second row of `X` to column `1` of `c` once. With that being said, it should be noted that `y` does not necessarily have to be `[1,1]`, it can also be `[0,1]`. In this case, we would add the first row of `X` to column `0` of `c` and the second row of `X` to column `1` of `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought when I saw your desired calculation, was to just sum the 2 rows of `X`, and add that to the 2nd column of `c`:

```
In [636]: c = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12]])

In [637]: c[:,1]+=X.sum(axis=0)

In [638]: c
Out[638]: 
array([[ 1, 13,  3],
       [ 4, 22,  6],
       [ 7, 34,  9],
       [10, 39, 12]])
```

But if we want to work from a general index like `y`, we need a special `bufferless` operation - that is if there are duplicates in `y`:

```
In [639]: c = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12]])

In [641]: np.add.at(c,(slice(None),y),X.T)

In [642]: c
Out[642]: 
array([[ 1, 13,  3],
       [ 4, 22,  6],
       [ 7, 34,  9],
       [10, 39, 12]])
```

You need to look up `.at` in the numpy docs.

in Ipython `add.at?` shows me the doc that includes:

> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand 'a' for elements
>   specified by 'indices'. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to
>   `a[indices] += b`, except that results are accumulated for elements that
>   are indexed more than once. For example, `a[[0,0]] += 1` will only
>   increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
>   `add.at(a, [0,0], 1)` will increment the first element twice.

With a different `y` it still works

```
In [645]: np.add.at(c,(slice(None),[0,2]),X.T)

In [646]: c
Out[646]: 
array([[11,  2,  4],
       [19,  5,  8],
       [27,  8, 15],
       [15, 11, 35]])
```

Comment: I don't know if it is more clear, but because `.T` returns a view, you can get the same result by transposing everything, which leads to a simpler indexing, i.e. `np.add.at(c.T, y, X)` produces the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for the excerpt on universal functions, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code seems to work in general if you transpose `X`. For example:

```
c = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12]])
X = array([[10, 15, 20,  5],
           [ 1,  2,  6, 23]]).transpose()
y = array([1, 2])

c[:,y] += X
print c
#OUTPUT:
#[[ 1 12  4]
# [ 4 20  8]
# [ 7 28 15]
# [10 16 35]]
```

However, it doesn't work when there are any duplicate columns in `y`, like in your specific example. I believe this is because `c[:, [1,1]]` will generate an array with two columns, each having the slice `c[:, 1]`. Both of these slices point to the same part of c, and so when the addition happens on each, they are both read, then the corresponding part of `X` is added to each, then they are written back, meaning the last one to be written back is the final value. I don't believe numpy will let you vectorize an operation like this because it fundamentally can't be. This requires editing one column at a time, saving back it's value, and then editing it again later.

You might have to settle for no duplicates, or otherwise implement something like an accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
def my_func(c, X, y):
    cc = np.zeros((len(y), c.shape[0], c.shape[1]))
    cc[range(len(y)), :, y] = X
    return c + np.sum(cc, 0)
```

The following interactive session demonstrates how it works:

```
>>> my_func(c, X, y)
array([[  1.,  13.,   3.],
       [  4.,  22.,   6.],
       [  7.,  34.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  39.,  12.]])
>>> y2 = np.array([0, 2])
>>> my_func(c, X, y2)
array([[ 11.,   2.,   4.],
       [ 19.,   5.,   8.],
       [ 27.,   8.,  15.],
       [ 15.,  11.,  35.]])
```